# ASP.NET GridView control with MySQL - UpdateQuery with spaces in parameters

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a project I'm making with Visual Studio 2010 and ASP.NET Web Forms. In it, I have a GridView control that I bound to a MySQL table. It displays my table in the control without a problem, but after I enabled editing on the control I found I had problems updating fields in the table when the field has a space in it.

For example, I have the following table defined:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
  `oid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_column` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `second_column` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `third column` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`oid`)
)
```

Note one of the fields has a space in the name. This is where I have problems. In my page, I have the following code:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="oid" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="oid" HeaderText="oid" ReadOnly="True" 
                SortExpression="oid" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="first_column" HeaderText="first_column" 
                SortExpression="first_column" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="second_column" HeaderText="second_column" 
                SortExpression="second_column" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="third column" HeaderText="third column" 
                SortExpression="third column" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testcon %>" 
        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testcon.ProviderName %>" 
        SelectCommand="select * from test_table" UpdateCommand="update `test_table` set
    `first_column`   = @first_column,
    `second_column`  = @second_column
where
    `oid` = @oid"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

By way of the UpdateCommand, I am able to update first_column and second_column on this table just fine. Now I want it to update `third column` the same way, but it doesn't work. If I change the query to this:

```
update `test_table` set
    `first_column`   = @first_column,
    `second_column`  = @second_column,
    `third column`   = @third column
where
    `oid` = @oid
```

It will give me this error when the query runs:

```
Parameter '@third' must be defined.
```

I've also tried @third\ column, @{third column}, @[third column], {@third column} - obviously none of these work. Therefore my question is: what do I put for my update query to be able to update my MySQL field that has a space in it?

Comment: there is space in `@third column`

Comment: Thank you @tunmise fasipe. That's the point of my question. I'm trying to reference the field of the same name, which legally contains a space.

Comment: May be you can change your schema to `third_column` to be consistent with other columns. Standard variables should not have space in them

Comment: If there is no way to reference the field with the space in it, then I will just have to change the schema. However, I'd rather keep my schema the way it is if that is possible. Why allow a field name if there is no way to reference it? So there ought to be a way.

Comment: variable name is different from column name. spaces are not allowed in variable. @third column is like a variable being passed to a function, the naming has to be valid

Comment: Right, so the question is then, while fields with contiguous names map to variables with contiguous names, what do fields with non-contiguous names map to? Isn't there a hash table that I can reference or something?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use any parameter name through the update parameters

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/accessing-the-database-directly-from-an-aspnet-page/inserting-updating-and-deleting-data-with-the-sqldatasource-vb

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testcon %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testcon.ProviderName %>" 
    SelectCommand="select * from test_table" UpdateCommand="update `test_table` set
`first_column`   = @first_column,
`second_column`  = @second_column
where `oid` = @oid">

   <UpdateParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="first_column" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="second_column" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="third_column" Type="String" />
   </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution to this situation is to provide an alias name to the column in the Select statement that populates the Gridview. For example:

```
SELECT ..., [third column] AS third_column, ...
FROM ...
```

And then you can use @third_column as the parameter name. Since I anticipate that you may want to show the column header with a space instead of an underscore, you can set the HeaderText property of this field to what you want.

With this approach, the Update command of the GridView will easily map to the corresponding parameter (since they have the same name) and you don't have to change the definitions in your database. I also recommend using SQLServer Profiler to see the actual T-SQL code that is executed in the server.

Good luck!